# Removing hashed password - cannot log in

Tags: php, hash

EDIT: Semi-solved. I can now store my insecure passwords in my DB and also log in. Next step is to give it another attempt at creating a secure mechanism for forgotten passwords (along with md5 encryption).

---

I'm trying to remove the md5 hashing from my passwords, so I can easily send the user his password to his email, in case he forgets it (I tried several solutions to generate a new password using md5 encryption, but I failed. So I want to do it this simple - yet a bit insecure - way).

I have the following code which stores the password in the database in a hashed format. I can also log in with no trouble... however as mentioned, I want to remove the hashing. I removed

```
$new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

and changed '$new_password' to '$upass'.

When I look at my database, I can see a non-hashed password which is exactly what I want. However, I can no longer log with a nonhashed password. Isn't that strange?  What am I possibly doing wrong?

Here's a snippet of my registration code.

```
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
$uname = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user_name']));
$email = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user_email']));
$upass = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));
$phone = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['phone']));

$new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$check_email = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE user_email='$email'");
$count=$check_email->num_rows;


if($count==0){


    $query = "INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_pass,user_phone) VALUES('$uname','$email','$new_password','$phone')";


    if($MySQLi_CON->query($query))
    {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; successfully registered !
                </div>";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; error while registering !
                </div>";
    }
}
else{


    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; sorry email already taken !
            </div>";

}

$MySQLi_CON->close();
```

}

Comment: "*I can see a non-hashed password which is exactly what I want.*" Which you really, really shouldn't want. The users trust their information with you, store it properly. Hash it, and create a "reset password" function instead.

Comment: It's not strange because your code is likely using `password_verify()` somewhere - and that expects a hash. And, as @Qirel said, you're doing it wrong. Passwords should have one way hashes, not encryption.

Comment: `I can no longer log with a nonhashed password` - does your login code hash the password? On a related note - why are you trying to removing the hashing? For the convenience of reminding the user what it is? Please don't... It's much better to re-set the password instead.

Comment: "a bit"? Please do consider that you often handle the users one and only password, meaning his/hers password for all sites/services.

Comment: Stop. Storing your users plain text passwords in a database and sending them via unencrypted email messages is _not_ "a bit insecure". It is a mile wide security gap severe enough that all your users should immediately stop using your service. You do not do that.

Comment: I've spent 50, if not many more, hours on re-setting passwords but I just couldn't figure out how to do it. I've followed several tutorials yet I failed. That's why I am forced to use a non-hashed password ... unless I can find someone to code it for me for an affordable price (not from here, of course. It's against the rules).

Yes, I do have password_verify().  Thank you, I modyfied that part of the code and now it woks :)

Comment: Hmm ... But my lack of knowledge and skills keeps me from storing the passwords securely :/

Comment: Actually you're not prevented from storing them securely - you were already doing it. What you need to do is implement, as @arkascha pointed out, a proper reset flow. There are many tutorials online for just this sort of thing.

Comment: I find it very odd that people click the "dislike"-button on my question. 
I asked a proper programming question.

Anyway ... I also hate that I cannot store the passwords securely ... but for now, I think I have to let it just be as it is.

Comment: That is not a 'dislike' button. Hover your mouse over the down arrow and you'll see the reasons for the DV's. They are not personal and should never be taken that way.

Comment: It always is a frustrating thing not to be able to resolve an issue. But please understand that few people here are willing to assist in a plan to make a service _less_ secure. Instead I really wish that you ask a question here with your attempt to implement a password reset flow that does not work. Specify the details _what_ exactly is not working, what problems you see and what your actual question is. Such a constructive question certainly would get good and helping feedback.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I have followed some very thorough tutorials. I was one able to get so far that I got a temp password sent to my email so I could reset it, but that's where I stopped getting any progress. I really really hate that I cannot store their passwords securely any longer. 

Regading the dislikes: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks :)

Comment: Why can't you store them securely any longer?

Comment: @arkasha, I dislike asking questions here. I get very "nerdy" replies which I can rarely use. I get disliked very often so I'm actually afraid of asking questions. 

I'll give it another try in a few days. I guess I have to make yet another attempt at solving this problem. As of right now, my passwords are really just in plain text in my database. Good thing is that it's not commercial yet.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, because if they forget their passwords, there is no way they can get it back. So they'd have to create a new account, because I havent implemented a reset function (tried hard ... will try again in afew days probably).

Comment: My plan is to keep my insecure way of storing passwords for a few days. I do not have any users (expect myself and a fake profiles) so I can afford to postpone it. 

I'll give it a try in a few days and when I get stuck, I will try here for help.

Comment: OK, in that special case (no real users), there is no risk, so you have all the time you need to find a great solution. About asking here: indeed sometimes there are nerdy words and replies that appear unnecessarily harsh, but please don't let that frustrate you. Think of it that way: if those people are wrong, then it is not your fault, is it? :-) You have a wealth of expertise and information at your fingertip here, so don't skip using it because of that. IN my personal experience it is typically very young and themselves unexperienced users posting such comments. You will fastly outgrow em.

Comment: @arkascha, thank you for your kind words. I'll make sure not to let "them" stop me from asking questions :)

Comment: That's the spirit! Go!! @Charles for the world!

Answer (score 1):

Stop.

Do not even think about anything which allows you (as a developer) to somehow get the plain text password of your users.

The solution to the original problem is very easy and does not involve storing your user's passwords in plaintext. If a user forgets his password, you do the following:

- Create a TAN (a long random number) and save it in your DB.
- Send the TAN to your user (integrated in a URL of course).
- When the user clicks the URL, he ends up in your website at your "password reset" feature.
- You ask him for his mail address or user name (whatever you use to identify users) and a new password.
- You look up the TAN, verify that it is the correct mail address or user name and delete it.
- You hash up the new password and store it in your DB.

(Of course, this assumes that the attacker is not able to get the mail; you may think about any number of further measures to make it safer. A popular one are "secrets" like "name of your first pet" etc.; you could send them an SMS, whatever... but that's another story).

At no point whatsoever are you handling plain text passwords, this is a total no-go and very neglient.

Comment: Or Don't Stop .. And give me the URL ;-)

Comment: " If you do this, you can also simply open up your website to anyone and remove the need to enter a password." 

How does that make sense? I mean, they need access to their own email to get the password. 

I will look into your solution. It sounds logical but I think it's going to be quite hard to do :D

Comment: That sentence was tongue-in-cheek, I have removed it.  The solution that I gave is not "mine", but it is what everyone does - try what happens if you forget your Stackoverflow password; you will not simply get your plaintext password sent to you...

Comment: Hmmm "Do not even think about anything which allows you (as a developer) to somehow get the plain text password of your users."... That would mean that we all immediately have to stop doing anything. ;-)

Comment: How so? Of course we are taking the plain password and hashing it  during some activities like logging in or setting/changing a password. But we are not trying to "un-hash" passwords, or storing them in a secondary location (however "secure" that may be) to be able to get their plaintext form.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

to

```
$new_password = $upass;
```

I too have had this problem. It worked with me when I changed it!